# Change character when keydown is held

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a simple way to change a character in an input field when the key is held down for more than 1second. For example holding down **a** would then change the character to **á**.
The exact thing I am looking to do can be seen on fluencia.com.
Also there is a need to be able to change the character if it is held for a further second.

So far, all I have done is detect the key held with the following code:

```
count = 0;
$(document).bind('keypress', function(e){

    keyisdown = false;
    key = e.which
        if (e.which === key) {
            keyisdown = true;
            count ++;
            if(count>1){

            }
        }
    }).bind('keyup',function(){
        keyisdown = false;
    count = 0;
    console.log('key up');
    });
```

Thanks
Adam

Comment: So far I have only got as far as detecting the held down key. Have added more info to the question.

Comment: how do you plan on finding the language equivalent of characters?

Comment: finding the language is not important as that is already defined within the webapp. that is I already know what the language will be and therefore can limit the characters that will trigger the change and what options they can change to.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for key "a".. You'll need to look up your keycode

```
var fired = false;
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 65) {
        var timer = setTimeout(function() {
            if (!fired) console.log('its held');
            fired = true;
        }, 1000);

        $(document).on("keyup", function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        });
    }
});
```

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/0a9rftt2/

Answer (score 0):

With help from Graham T above and a bit of playing around I come up with the following:

```
var fired = false;
var keycode = null;
var key = null;

$("#loginEmail").on("keypress", function(e) {
   keycode = e.which;
   key = String.fromCharCode(keycode);
});


$("#loginEmail").on("keydown", function(e) {
    var s = this.value;
    var str = this.value;

    if (e.keyCode == 65) {

        var timer = setTimeout(function() {
            if (!fired) console.log('its held');
            fired = true;
            if(fired){
                s = $("#loginEmail").val();
                str = s.substring(0, s.length - 1);
                replacewith = 'á';
                str = str+replacewith;
                $("#loginEmail").val(str);
            }
        }, 500);

        $(document).on("keyup", function() {

            clearTimeout(timer);
            fired = false;
        });
    }
});
```

It is not cleaned up as yet. I had to use keypress to get the true character (capitalised or not) and then used keydown to detect key being held down.